# analytics if on production site, not a local or heroku subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, heroku, localhost, analytics

This question is about getting an analytics script to run in one of these three environments.

1. mysite.heroku.com
2. mysite-staging.heroku.com
3. mysite.com - this is the only one I want it to run on.

This is how I plan to lay it out, but any suggestions are welcome.

In my helper

```
def render_analytics
  if local_request? || #on a Heroku subdomain 
     false
  else
     true
  end
end
```

In my layout

```
<%= render 'shared/analytics' if render_analytics %>
```

`render_analytics` returns a boolean: `true` if on mysite.com, `false` if a `local_request?` or on a Heroku subdomain (ex: mysite.heroku.com `||` mysite-staging.heroku.com)

So how can I find out if it is coming from Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hostname`:

```
if local_request? || `hostname` =~ /heroku/i
```

A cleaner solution is to set a constant in your environment during deployment that allows you to know whether you are on Heroku. As the Heroku deploy process is pretty opaque in terms of letting you dork around with config files, you might have your method memoize the result so you aren't doing a system call each time you render a view.

I just did something similar with a method that checks the database adapter to account for differences between my development environment and Heroku. Here's my `lib/adapter.rb`:

```
class Adapter
  cattr_reader :adapter

  def self.postgres?
    @@adapter ||= Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]['adapter']
    adapter == 'postgresql'
  end

  def self.mysql?
    @@adapter ||= Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]['adapter']
    adapter == 'mysql'
  end

  def self.sqlite?
    @@adapter ||= Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]['adapter']
    adapter.include?('sqlite')
  end
end
```

Note that in addition to this, you have to change `application.rb` such that `lib` is added to your autoload path:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"] # include all subdirectories
```

Comment: such as in `initializers/constants.rb`? Do i need to include action pack, how to do that, I've never seen logic in a constant file... how to do that?